# AngularJs - passing parameters from grid result rows to external webpage

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I am working on a webapp built upon angularjs.So,i have a search result UI built which upon search displays result in grid.Now,when user clicks on each row of the result ,an external webpage should be called with values of columns passed from  that clicked grid row to the external webpage.

How can i do this,can i have a sample controller to refer upon.

Please help with this

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send an AJAX call to some JSON api when a user clicks on some element. Here's a basic thing of how to do that in an angularjs controller:

```
angular.module("your.app")
.controller("ajaxingCtrl",["$http","$scope", function($http, $scope){
    $scope.onSomeUserAction = function(argument){
        //substitute the type of request your api requires
        $http.get("http://your.remote.api/some/resource", 
        {
         //params will get parsed into HTTP query parameters
         params: {
                  x:arguments.x
                 }
        }
        ).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);// and then do what you will with the result
        })
    }
}])
```

You can find more information about doing ajax calls in [angular's $http service docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: Is it possible for me to embed a link in kendo grid paramenters  in html of page and pass the parameters to it.